# Apple's BetterAuthorizationSample doesn't work on 10.6.6

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, macos, objective-c++

The install tool failed to install the helper tool with code 100001 after update of the system to 10.6.6. Any ideas what might be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Solved: If you have the same problem you have to delete the folder Library/PriviligedHelperTool, which was previously created by the installer tool

Answer (score 0):

There is SampleUninstall.sh script in BetterAuthorizationSample folder. You can use it to uninstall helper tool and unregister it with launchd.